# Unable to create meeting with Zoom API (response code 200)

Tags: python, django, zoomus, zoom-sdk

I'm using the zoomus(https://github.com/prschmid/zoomus/) Python module to create a Zoom meeting via the Zoom API. However, I did notice that when using client.meeting.create(), I'm getting an http response code of 200 (not 201) which I think means the response is successful but the meeting isn't created.

The call I'm making in my django app:

```
# create Zoom meeting
client = ZoomClient('xxx', 'xxxx')

zoom_format = Event.start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
zoom_meeting = client.meeting.create(topic="Meeting", type=2, start_time=str(zoom_format), duration=30, userId=str(updatedEvent.user.email), agenda="", 
host_id=str(updatedEvent.mentor_user.email))
print(zoom_meeting)
```

The response I'm getting is a 200, but it needs to be 201 in order to actually create the meeting:

```
{
"endpoint": "https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/xxx/meetings",
"response_headers": [
"Set-Cookie: zm_aid=""; Domain=.zoom.us; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly"
],
"date_time": "2020-07-28 06:52:33",
"method": "GET",
"request_body": "N/A",
"response": {
"page_size": 30,
"total_records": 0,
"next_page_token": "",
"meetings": [
]
},
"request_headers": [
"accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
"accept: */*",
"authorization: ******",
"connection: close",
"user-agent: python-requests/2.24.0"
],
"request_params": [
"user_id: xxx"
],
"http_status": "200"
}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? It looks like the only required information is the date and the userID which I did supply.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: please where you able to get that solved? I am getting {'code': 124, 'message': 'Invalid access token.'}. Please how did you get to this point. Thanks